# Windows 7 acting as router

Tags: networking, lan

I have a LAN with four clients, one server and one modem that connects to the Internet.

The configuration is the following:

Modem/Router IP:

```
10.211.47.156/8
```

Server IP:

```
10.0.0.1/8
```

Clients:

```
10.0.0.2/8-10.0.0.5/8
```

When I assign default gateway of clients to 10.0.0.1 they navigate to the internet correctly as if their default gateway was the modem ip (10.211.47.156)

When I trace the connection to the internet I found that the server machine is forwarding the packets:

```
1 - 10.0.0.1
2 - 10.211.47.156
3 - *
4 - ...
```

This ocurs only if the default gateway of the server machine is set to the modem ip (10.211.47.156)

Besides that configuration the server machine isn't configured in any other way ( no shared internet connection, no external programs, not bridges).

The server machine is running Windows 7 Ultimate

**How can I prevent clients to connect directly to the internet if their default gateway must be the server?**

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: I don't understand why you this behavior isn't normal?   Your using the server to share your internet connection, it's suppose to forward the traffic, it's doing exactly what the modem would be doing

Comment: sounds like you're trying [if accidentally] to use a server as a gateway - don't have the server handing out DHCP & don't set its IP address to be the gateway address…. [also, don't use a consumer OS as a gateway or sever, it's not very good at it]

Comment: I want my clients to connect to a proxy transparently, with out adding directly proxy settings, that's why I use the server IP as gateway, but is clear that I don't understand correctly what's happening, that's why I asked. I want them by example to request a page at tcp/80 and ask the server for it, no that the server forwards the request to the modem and finally to the internet.

Comment: I don't think you understand the subnetting notation you're using (/8) and how packets move within and across networks. Packets are always addressed to the gateway on the network. That gateway then passed it on the next gateway, and so on, until it reaches it's destination. So if you have all your machines pointing to the server as their gateway, for the packets to ever go anywhere else, the server needs to know what to do with them, which is why the server gateway must be the modem/router - that will then pass the packets on. Look up router/gateway and CIDR on wikipedia for more details.

Comment: You're are right, a didn't know about that. You may write that as an answer so I can mark it as answered. Thanks